# Pass value to Django model attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am building a file upload page where files will be saved with a different prefix in their name (get_file_path function uses instance.mname) but will go through the same upload model/form. I want the prefix to be declared in the views in form in mname='prefix'. How can I pass this value from views to form?

Thank you!

models.py

```
class Upload(models.Model):

    mname = # need it to be passed
    document = models.FileField(upload_to=get_file_path, validators=[validate_file_extension])
    upload_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add =True)
```

forms.py

```
class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Upload
        fields = ('document',)
```

views.py

```
def uploadFile(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        file = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES, mname='....')
        if file.is_valid():
           file.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a parameter to the `__init__` of the form:

```
UploadForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, path, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UploadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['document'] = forms.FileField(upload_to=path, validators=[validate_file_extension])
```

And initializing the form with this parameter:

```
file = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES, path='...')
```

Comment: thank you! seems very close to working but returns __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'upload_to'

Comment: Have you tried it without the validators ... this one I just copied from your example but probably does not belong here.

Comment: I think it's maybe because you can't not use a model with file upload